# Closest date per id

Tags: ms-access-2010, datediff

I am trying to find the closest following date for a per date per ID. Each ID on the primary list (T1) may have multiple dates and for each I want to return the closest following date on a seperate table (T2).

Primary table I need closest following dates for;

**T1**

```
PID ES Date
16  03/09/2009
17  29/07/2009
17  26/01/2012
18  19/02/2010
```

The table with multiple entries per ID

**T2**

```
SERVICEID   PID APPOINTMENT
14          16  03/09/2009
14          16  14/09/2009
14          16  21/09/2009
20          17  22/07/2009
20          17  06/08/2009
20          17  22/10/2009
20          17  24/11/2009
20          17  05/01/2010
38402       17  25/01/2012
38402       17  21/02/2012
38402       17  03/04/2012
38402       17  08/05/2012
17          18  01/10/2009
4982        18  16/02/2010
6499        18  28/04/2010
6499        18  12/05/2010
6499        18  16/06/2010
6499        18  15/07/2010
```

What I would like to return
**T3**

```
PID ES Date     SERVICEID   APPOINTMENT
16  03/09/2009  14          03/09/2009
17  29/07/2009  20          22/07/2009
17  26/01/2012  38402       25/01/2012
18  19/02/2010  6499        28/04/2010
```

I have looked at a number if simular questions using DATEDIFF, ABS, MIN ect but am unable to get something working for what i want. I am using MSAccess 2010.

Comment: pick one : mysql or access and fix your tags

Answer (score 0):

Do a join, use `WHERE` to return only the minimum following date.

```
select t1.PID, t1.ES, t1.Date,
       t2.SERVICEID, t2.APPOINTMENT
from t1 join t2 on t1.pid = t2.pid
where t2.date = (select min(date) from t2
                 where date > t1.date
                   and pid = t1.pid)
```

Comment: can you explaine what 'min(date)' refers too. Is it A field or function. Thx's for your time

Comment: I have tried to convert your code so it runs on Access but am getting an error with the join. 'SELECT  T1.[Patient ID], 
  T1.[Date Referral Received], 
  T1.[ES Date], 
  T2.SERVICEID, 
  T2.APPOINTMENT

  FROM (T1 
   INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.[Patient ID] = T2.LPTID
   
 
   WHERE T2.APPOINTMENT =  (SELECT MIN(date) FROM T2
         WHERE date > T1.[ES Date]
         AND T2.LPTID = T1.[Patient ID])'

Comment: It's t2's date column, so guess it should be min(t2.[Date]). I'm sorry, but I don't know Access SQL very well.

Comment: Not a problem, does anyone know how to write a query in accessSQL, prob not.